# AWS Lambda Report batch item failures with SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

The Lambda response is

```
{
  "errorMessage": "handler returns a single value, but it does not implement error",
  "errorType": "errorString"
}
```

ref [aws document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#example-standard-queue-message-event)

The example shows that only need to return fail messages without error.

And I have enabled the `Report batch item failure` option in Lambda trigger.

My golang code in lambda is like

```
type SQSBatchResponse struct {
    BatchItemFailures []SQSMessage 
}

type SQSMessage struct {
    MessageId string
}

func Handler(_ context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) (sqsResponse SQSBatchResponse) {
    // code
    return sqsResponse
}
```

Comment: The error tells you what is needed. You forgot to return the error, as it is required in the handler function.
It should be something like this:
`func Handler(_ context.Context, sqsEvent events.SQSEvent) (sqsResponse SQSBatchResponse, error)`.

Check out this link for valid handler signatures: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html

Comment: @EminLaletovic Because I tried to return (sqsResponse,error) which error is nil, but sqs still ignore the fail items and deleted all of them.
Maybe I should return error not nil? Not sure it will delete successful message or not..

Comment: The docs are not clear on this since the examples are written in other languages. Things I would recommend you to try: 
1. Try returning a non-nil error to see if that will help.
2. Check if the event source mapping of your lambda function contains `ReportBatchItemFailures` in the `FunctionResponseTypes` field. This is needed so that only failed messages are returned in the queue and not deleted.
Useful links 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#services-sqs-batchfailurereporting
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_ListEventSourceMappings.html

Comment: I have tried returning nil or non-nil error with (SQSBatchResponse, error), but it olny do delete all or return all messages depending on value of error.
I will use batch delete messages manually instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the response structure should be like this.

[Aws-lambda-go](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events#SQSEventResponse)

```golang
type SQSEventResponse struct {
    BatchItemFailures []SQSBatchItemFailure `json:"batchItemFailures"`
}

type SQSBatchItemFailure struct {
    ItemIdentifier string `json:"itemIdentifier"`
}
```

Comment: `func SqsEmailHandler(ctx context.Context, e events.SQSEvent) (events.SQSEventResponse, error)` worked for me with the response structure above. eg. only failed messages were retried in SQS.